# É possivel fusionar o pronome direto dum predicado nominal com o pronome indireto?

Tags: gramática, pronomes

Se tivermos uma pergunta como a seguinte:

> É a aula muito difícil para ti?

Sei que é possível responder assim com objeto direto:

> É-o para mim.

Igualmente, é possível responder assim com pronome indireto:

> É-me difícil, sim.

Então, é possível responder assim?

> É-mo, sim.

Comment: Oh joy! An emo question! :)

Comment: @tchrist Quer-me parecer que sabes qualquer coisa que não nos estás a contar!

Answer (score 4):

Em Portugal nós fazemo-lo:

> Quando me devolves o livro? — Devolvo-to amanhã.
>
> Já alguém lhe contou o que se passou? — Contei-lho eu hoje.
>
> Fazes-me um favor? — Far-to-ei com prazer.

Com o *nos* ou *vos* + artigo é diferente:

> Sei uma história interessantíssima! — Conta-no-la, vá lá! — Contar-vo-la-ei, tenham calma.

Para confirmar, escrevi isto no Word, e nem um milímetro de sublinhado vermelho!

Agora, nos exemplos acima, **o** e **a** representam substantivos ou expressões como **o que se passou**, enquanto no exemplo da pergunta, **o** representa o adjetivo *difícil*. Resta saber se também isto é gramatical. Eu terei que investigar isto melhor, mas para já arrisco que sim. Apesar de *é-mo, sim* não me soar bem, o exemplo abaixo é gramaticalmente idêntico e já me agrada. (*É-mo, sim* não me soa bem por ser ultrabreve e não se ganhar nada em relação a *é-me difícil, sim*.)

> A aula foi difícil para ti? — Foi-mo, e de que maneira!

Agora, em conversa coloquial, o mais certo seria dizermos simplesmente, "Foi, e de que maneira!"

Tenho ideia que no Brasil (amigos brasileiros, pronunciai-vos!) estas contrações são menos usadas que em Portugal, o que uma única consulta a este [Corpus do Portugês](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) parece confirmar. Da pesquisa de *é-me* resultaram 57 ocorrências de autores portugueses e apenas duas de autores brasileiros! E as duas do princípio do século XX.

Comment: Sei que e possível quando se trata dum substantivo, mas não sabia se for possível quando o objeto é atributivo (ao menos, é o término usado em espanhol e asturiano para o pronome neutro usado para adjetivos com ser, não sei o seu equivalente no português)

Comment: Referes-te a coisas como o teu exemplo, em que "o" representa "difícil"? Mesmo que soubesse os termos em português, provavelmente _eu não os saberia!_

Comment: Refero-me sim. É sempre *-o* sem importância do género do substantivos ao que se aplica. O meu professor (brasileiro) disse que era impossível, mas mesmo dizia que ninguém diria *é-me*. Mas como vi várias vezes coisas como *é-me*, não sabia se houvesse uma restrição gramatical verdadeira, mera falta de uso popular mas compreensível, o se for muito comum.

Comment: _É-me difícil_ está definitivamente correto. Ninguém diria _é-me_ será meramente um exagero dele, para dizer que, talvez especialmente no Brasil, é incomum? Parece-me que, na linguagem coloquial, os brasileiros usam menos estas contrações do que os portugueses.

Comment: Num corpus do português encontrei 57 ocorrências de  _é-me_ em autores portugueses, e só dois em autores brasileiros, ambos do princípio do século XX.

Comment: E com o *o* de difícil como em *é-mo*? Como soaria para os portugueses modernos —é dizer, soa natural/forçado/mal a resposta *é-mo, sim* para dizer *É difícil para mim*?

Comment: Já te dei o +1, mas seria bom adicionar esse exemplo teu na resposta (e claro, mas logo se encontrares alguma fonte). Qual é o corpus que usas?

Comment: A mim não me soa nada bem nem *É-mo* nem *Foi-mo*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pode ser uma questão de falta de hábito. "Contar-vo-la-ei" soa-te bem?

Comment: @Jacinto soa-me bem embora não se use muito.